# Monitoring the displacement of a mobile device using GPS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cordova

I am wanting to develop an application for mobile devices, which shows in real time where a user (with this software installed on your mobile device) is. The idea would be that one (or more) users could follow the map the displacement of another user via GPS. I want to use PhoneGap with HTML5 and CSS and Javascript.

My question is: Is it possible to do that with these technologies? If yes, where can I get information of how to handle the GPS that way? If you can not, which language would give me this possibility and where can I get information? At first, I intend to develop this Application for Android and IOS.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly possible and there are tons of publications on this topic. Please use Google before asking this kind of questions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but even seeming lie, yes I have researched (I may not have used the correct terms), including his own stackoverflow suggested to me some related posts which I gave it a read and have not found wha I was looking for. But I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it’s very much possible with PhoneGap technology.  You have to write a web service to keep the GPS coordinates as user updates (or auto updates) in server. You can let other users to connect to Web service and get the info they wanted (i.e. the data they wanted to see the current location of the user). You developed using PhoneGap means, it’ll work for iPhone too.

You can easily develop a web service either using PHP, Java or C# though C# web services are easy to write and maintain but PHP web servers are cheap compare to windows hosting (which you will need to host C# web service).

The question you asked is very broad so can write a 1000 words article and beyond. If you ask specific question I can answer that.